# Choosing OS X version for mid-2012 MacBook Air 6,2 with 4GB RAM (EMC 2559)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade

### The situation

I have a mid-2012 MacBook Air 5,2 (13'' A1466 EMC 2559) that I plan to sell.

It is currently running OS X 10.7 Lion (for which Safari is obsolete).
I want to **upgrade it** to a newer version, **without compromising performance**, as I want the buyer being happy with his purchase.

I'm **looking for feedback** from those who **actually upgraded** their **MacBook Air 6,2 (mid-2012)** with **i5 and 4GB RAM** to any of these versions: **El Capitan / Sierra / High Sierra / Mojave**.

Here are the specs:

- i5 @ 1.8 Ghz
- 4GB RAM (DDR3)
- 384 MB VRAM
- 500 GB SSD (replacement from 256 GB original one)

The generous graphic card, the SSD and the relatively fast processor should still make it a very decent computer for office use. It should run without problem a system like Windows 10. However, some users reported 4GB RAM being not enough for recent Mac OS X versions.

### Result of my investigations so far

Officially, the MacBook Air 6,2 can be upgraded up to Catalina (10.15).
However,you have to stay to Mojave (10.14) or below if you still want keeping the ability to run 32-bit apps.

I read here and there that some users of MacBook from 2012 encountered performance issues when upgrading to High Sierra and upper. However, I'm not sure if this is because they were possibly using MacBook Pro and consequently HDD (if no SSD upgrade done), since recent OS X versions are optimized for SSD, or if recent OS X versions are very RAM-hungry to run well.

With an SSD, i5 and 4GB RAM, I'm pretty confident that there should be no performance issues with OS X El Capitan (10.11).
I have some doubt for OS X Sierra (10.12), and more doubt with OS X High Sierra (10.13) and Mojave (10.14).

Although I could clone the existing OS and come back to it in case of any perfomance issue, in order to save time I would prefer upgrading directly to the latest possible version known to be without performance issue.
Thank you for your feeback.

Comment: High Sierra runs fine on my MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2011) with 4 GB. It has an SSD from factory.